# Run programs on remote computer

Tags: c#, wmi, remote-server

I have this code:

```
ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", sHost), connOptions);
manScope.Connect();
ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);
ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
inParams["CommandLine"] = "notepad.exe";
ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
```

When I set sHost to be my local IP address, it works and notepad opens.
However, when I set it to be the remote server, nothing happens.

(I'm able to connect to the remote computer and copy files from my application - this is just for trying to run stuff remotely. Firewall has also been configure for WMI).

Kinda have no more ideas...

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you have checked Notepad isn't running in the background on the remote machine (look in Task Manager)? You aren't hooking up to a logged on user's desktop session, so it probably won't show on screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I checked, but nothing runs it doesn't run in the background. I also tried to set the Username and Password to the "connOptions", but still nothing...

Comment: can u check the value of outParams["returnValue"] and outParams["processId"] ?

Comment: Oh, now it works...I had to add the Authority to "connOptions" in order to enter a domain. Now it runs ok! The issue now is what Rhumborl mentioned in the first place - the process runs in the background (can be shown in task manager). Is there any way around it? Also, "notepad" was an example, when in fact I'm running a batch script. When the script finishes, "cmd" is left running in the background..Any way to get over it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you should use PsTools (run from your app) ? Ideally for remote deploying.

Comment: PS Tools are way faster than the WMI route trust me.